# Git push from GitLab to remote

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a fresh GitLab instalation for a private PHP Web Application and I want to be able to deploy my application on master push in gitlab.

After some reading, I undestood I can do this with webhook on the live application which pull from gitlab repo to deploy changes.

The problem is my gitlab installation is on a local network server which is unreachable from my live server.

So I want to be able to push from my gitlab repo to the live server in place of pull from my live server.

How can I do this ? I haven't find how to add remote and push from the gitlab repo.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very backwards. If you want to use git for deployment, why not just create a git repository on the PHP server with a hook which pulls from itself?

Something like this:

```
www-data ~ $ ls
your-app.git
your-app

www-data ~ $ cat your-app.git/hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh

unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)
cd ~/your-app
git pull

www-data ~ $ ls -l your-app.git/hooks
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   76 Nov  5 23:14 post-receive

www-data ~ $ cd your-app
www-data your-app $ git remote -v
origin ../your-app.git (fetch)
origin ../your-app.git (push)
```

You'd then update the content on the PHP server by pushing to the repository on the PHP server.

Comment: I would like to, but I have have infrasctructure problem, I need to have gitlab locally because the live server is on the other face of the world, there is maibe a solution to this but this is what my cie decided. I maybe can try your solution but with "push to"  in place of "pull from"